# How to use recursive CTE with LOOKUP?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a very specific use-case for which I'm not even sure if I can use SQL operators.

I have a `users` table, a `branches` table, and a `users_to_branches` view. `users_to_branches` view exists, because I need `id`, `username`, and `branch_id` from `users`, and a `branch_name` (not present in `users`) and a `parentBranch_id` from `branches` table.

Now the organizational chart can be structured in a couple of layers, so as of now `branch_id` of a user, is a direct branch to which the user is assigned (ex. Finance), but the `parentBranch_id` is a level above that (ex. Company X). But for example, if there's one more layer, under Finance (ex. Bookkeeping), `parentBranch_id` would be Finance's `branch_id`. What I need, is to see the highest level of the structure as the `parentBranch_id` at all times. So in the case of Bookkeeping as `branch_id` I want to see Company X as `parentBranch_id`.

What kind of logic am I looking at? I've read it will have to involve recursive CTE, but how to implement a LOOKUP function and pass the value with it?

My thinking: The function has to constantly check the `parentBranch_id`. IF NULL, then pass the `branch_id` as `parentBranch_id`. IF NOT NULL then look up the `parentBranch_id` value in the `branch_id` column - until it's NULL.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve].

Comment: As I understand your Branches table is trivial parent-child structure. Use it by the common way in recursive CTE starting from root rows and generate the representation `(ID-parentID-rootID)` (or `(ID-fullPath)`). Then join another tables and retrieve needed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the ultimate parent branch for each branch id using a recursive CTE.  Something like this:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select b.branch_id as ultimate_parent_branch_id, b.branch_id as branch_id
      from branches b
      where parent_branch_id is null
      union all
      select cte.ultimate_parent_branch_id, b.branch_id
      from cte join
           branches b
           on b.parent_branch_id = cte.branch_id           
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Then you would just use this by joining back to `users`:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select b.branch_id as ultimate_parent_branch_id, b.branch_id as branch_id
      from branches b
      where parent_branch_id is null
      union all
      select cte.ultimate_parent_branch_id, b.branch_id
      from cte join
           branches b
           on b.parent_branch_id = cte.branch_id           
     )
select *
from users u join
     user_branches ub
     on u.user_id = ub.user_id join
     cte
     on cte.branch_id = ub.branch_id;
```